# System occasionally freezes and will not restart though power is present

Tags: freeze

I use my desktop PC mostly for watching TV, downloading stuff and sometimes playing big games. Recently, I've been having some weird problems which I am unable to attribute to a particular component. Sometimes, irrespective of what I am doing, the monitor just switches off/goes blank and the system becomes dead!

I can see the power light glowing in the chassis, but none of the components seem to work, even the restart button. I thought the problem might be a loose contact between some components inside the chassis, so I opened the box, removed dust, re-fitted the TV tuner and graphics card. Still the problem persists.

I have yet to try switching off the UPS and then starting everything again. Is this a problem with my video card? How can I diagnose/fix this problem?

Specs:

- nVidia 8600GT graphics card
- Core2Duo processor
- Intel motherboard
- Pinnacle TV tuner
- 3GB of RAM
- Windows XP

Comment: Have you looked in the event log to see if there is anything there?

Comment: You mean, After the restart? I checked during one restart, but not for all restarts i have done so far. No errors!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you should check if there is a software condition that triggers the freeze. You can check if it only occurs running some kind of applications. For example, tv applications crashes may indicate a faulty tv tuner or video card, and crashes playing games that make intensive use of graphics may indicate a faulty video card.

There are many possible hardware causes: power supply unit, video card, tv tuner, system RAM, temperature issues (overheating), etc.

To check for hardware problems, you can start by disconnecting components one at a time and test your system. When you reconnect those components, they should be working again automatically.

To check for a faulty video card, you can try connecting the onboard video integrated on you motherboard (if it's available) or connecting a replacement card.

System RAM can be checked running Memtest from a live CD (you can use [SystemRescueCd](http://www.sysresccd.org))

To check the PSU you can replace it or look for incorrect voltages and temperatures through BIOS setup.

Some causes of overheating are failing fans and dust blocking air flow.

Comment: THanks for giving multiple options to check! I am trying one by one. I dont see any crashes with respect to software because its just going dead irrespective of what i do... Even if the computer is downloading something overnight and doing nothing else, it will be dead when i wake up and see it in the morning.. I am going to look into hardware sides now...

Comment: Seems to be problem with PSU... :) replacing it is working like a charm! Thanks a lot for pointing in right direction!

Comment: You are welcome. I'm glad it helped. Generic PSUs are specially very likely to fail (and endanger all other components).